# Print out all subsets in an array that equal an given sum recursively does not jump to the next iteration

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to print out all the subsets that is equal to a given sum using recursion. However, my code doesn't jump to the next iteration after the first one is finished:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Combinations {
public static int currentSum = 0;
public static ArrayList<Integer> usedItems = new ArrayList<>();
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {

    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 2};
    int sum = 6;
    printCombinations(arr, sum);
}

public static void printCombinations(int[] availableItems, int goal){

    for (int i = 0; i < availableItems.length; i++){
        if (currentSum + availableItems[i] == goal){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(usedItems.toArray()) + availableItems[i]);
            currentSum = 0;
            usedItems.clear();
        }
        if(currentSum + availableItems[i] > goal){
            continue;
        }
        if(currentSum + availableItems[i] < goal){
            currentSum += availableItems[i];
            usedItems.add(availableItems[i]);
            int[] newAvailableItems = Arrays.copyOfRange(availableItems, 1, availableItems.length);
            printCombinations(newAvailableItems, goal);
        }
    }
}
```

For example if the sum equals 6 the program only prints out 1, 2, 3 but not jump to the next number and check from there.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
 if (currentSum + availableItems[i] == goal)
```

For the given array `int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 2};` and goal value `int sum = 6;`

Iterations:

1. `currentSum = 0, availableItems[i] = 1` (0 + 1 = 1) fits -> `if(currentSum + availableItems[i] < goal)`
2. `currentSum = 1, availableItems[i] = 2` (1 + 2 = 3) fits -> `if(currentSum + availableItems[i] < goal)`
3. `currentSum = 3, availableItems[i] = 3` (3 + 3 = 6) fits -> `if (currentSum + availableItems[i] == goal)` and in the same iteration: `currentSum = 0, availableItems[i] = 3` (0 + 3 = 3) fits -> `if (currentSum + availableItems[i] < goal)`
4. `currentSum = 3, availableItems[i] = 4` (3 + 4 = 7)
   fits -> `if(currentSum + availableItems[i] > goal)` and so on...

For the given array and sum value is not going to fit the first if never.

You need increase the iterator:

```
if (currentSum + availableItems[i] == goal){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(usedItems.toArray()) + availableItems[i]);
    currentSum = 0;
    usedItems.clear();
    i++;
}
```

Comment: But if the sum = 1, the program will never print out because at this point the currentSum still equals 0. In fact, switching to your solution doesn't print out the solution at all

Comment: Well, you have to consider two things. A. With your given array and sum value, currentSum will be 6 in the 4th iteration (0 + 1 + 2 + 3). B. If sum = 1 it will only print out when currentsum=1 due the rest of elements are bigger than 1.

Comment: No, that array is just an example. In the actual program, it will prompt users to enter the arrays and the sum value.